# how to achieve this particular layout using css?

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve this layout:

[image]

So far, here is the HTML I have:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="nav">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
#content{
margin:0 auto;
height:1200px;
width:1000px;
border:2px solid black;
}
#header{
margin:0 auto;
width:inherit;
height:200px;
border-bottom:2px black solid;
}
#nav{
margin:0 auto;
width:inherit;
height:50px;
border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
#footer{
width:inherit;
border-top:2px solid black;
margin-top:-1200px;
height:200px;
clear:both;
}
```

The problem is with the footer - it is not behaving as in diagram.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code? Please don't give me some other codes because I am new to CSS.

Comment: Why do you have `margin-top: -1200px` on your footer? Aslo, even though this will neither fix nor break anything, why do you have `clear: both` on your footer? What is `clear: both` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your footer is moved up because you have margin-top: -1200px